# jquery-ui datepicker with showOn: button showed even if source input is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have an input text field with a `datepicker` instance from jquery-ui with the following parameters:

```
'buttonImageOnly': true,
'showOn': 'button',
'buttonImage': 'gfx/calendar.gif'
```

It works well. When I click the "calendar.gif" datepicker image, the calendar is shown. However, when I select a date, the input field (which was disabled) is changed.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?  When I look at the instance object in Firebug, the `disabled` parameter is set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Disabled mean you can't manually write in it. But you still can with javascript.

The textbox is where it saves the date value. If you don't want it to show, turn it to a hidden field or hide it with CSS (easier).

The buttonImageOnly is about using a button with an image type or just an image.

I don't see any bug nor error from your part. :)

Comment: Well, but how to prevent using datepicker from image when input field is disabled (by other module in CMS).

Comment: The other module that disable the link should also disable the image. The easy way would be to hide or erase it. Otherwise, you need to find what event it is binded to or use db-disable(). Either that or rewrite the datepicker function to check if the field is disabled. See [this example](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerDisabled.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care that the image will no longer show, try the following:

```
$('#myfield:not([disabled])').datepicker();
```